# PHP anonymous functions chaining

Tags: php, anonymous-function

```
$app = 'App here';


$fn1 = function($var) use($app){
    $fn2($var);
};

$fn2 = function($var) use($app){
    echo $var;
};

$fn1('variable');
```

In the above example, I am trying to chain/forward multiple anonymous functions. However, at the below line I receive an error "Notice: Undefined variable: fn2"

```
$fn2($var)
```

How do I achieve the chaining of anonymous functions.

Comment: Pass `$fn2` as an argument to `$fn1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing the `$fn2` as a parameter in the `use` statement of the closure.

Try the following code:

```
    $app = 'App here';

    $fn2 = function($var) use($app){
       echo $var;
    };

    $fn1 =  function($var) use($app, $fn2){
       $fn2($var);
    };

    $fn1('variable');
```

[Here you have your example working in an online php tester.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8731b78434b797e6ac69b421e7f7afdfa846520)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that your variable `$fn2` is out of scope in your first anonymous function. So just put the assignment of `$fn2` before `$fn1` and then pass the variable as you already did in the `use()`, e.g. `$fn1 = function($var) use($app, $fn2){`

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify a few things first, chaining is something traditionally attributed to the **Object Oriented Paradigm** (*as in method chaining*), whereby one method returns an instance in order to *chain* multiple method calls together on the return value of each successive method.

In a **functional paradigm** what you're doing is more commonly referred to as a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) - *or a function whose argument takes another function or returns a function*.

The problem with your existing code is that functions in PHP do not implicitly import variables from the global scope (see [variable scoping in PHP](http://php.net//language.variables.scope)) or any other block scope. The only caveat being that they do gain access to `$this` or the object instance when they are defined within object context (i.e. inside of a class method that is not static). [At least as of PHP 5.4](http://php.net/functions.anonymous#functions.anonymous).

So instead you must explicitly import variables from the global or local scope outside of the closure by using the `use` statement, which you have used to import the variable `$app` in your example. Though, importing variables touching the outer scope may not always be an elegant solution within a functional paradigm, assuming that is what you're going for.

So in the essence of a higher order function you can more succinctly express your code in the following manner...

```
$app = 'App here';


$fn1 = function($fn2, $var) use($app){
    $fn2($var);
};

$fn2 = function($var) use($app){
    echo $var;
};

$fn1($fn2, 'variable');
```

Which would give you the output `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `$fn2` before you use the variable

EDIT: and to pass the variable in the `use()`

```
$app = 'App here';

$fn2 = function($var) use($app){
    echo $var;
};

$fn1 = function($var) use($app, $fn2){
    $fn2($var);
};

$fn1('variable');
```

Comment: The variable `$fn2` still will be out of scope in the anonymous function